# Unable to edit List column which is updated by SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

In SharePoint List I'm updating the column using SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013. For Example if I enter 40 no manually in second item then SPD 2013 will deduct from 100 an update 60 in first row which is working fine.

Now let assume 40 no is wrong entry and I want to change the no from 40 to 30 in second row/item. Then here the problem is the changes is not reflect in first row / item (it should show 100-30 = 70) which shows old value 60 only.

Any suggestion please.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you change the wording of your question to make it more understandable. Could you post exactly what your workflow is meant to do?

Comment: Hi Vince I've done the changes. Hope this will be clear.

Comment: Devang - I change the workflow, PFA print screen, In starting only the result is coming incorrect. Its showing result something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your workflow set to trigger on Item Update? I doubt on this.

There are checkbox in the Edit Workflow page.
you should enable "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed"

Please let me know in case more help is required.

[image]

EDITED ANSWER as per OP's Comment.

Devang / Vince - Yes after select "then update item in current list" but "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" now its updating. But its treating as a new value. For example (First Deliver Qty 200-10=190 then 190-15=175) so here if I'm editing the Qty from 15 to 20 so it will show the result (190-20=170) but result which I'm getting is (175-20=155) which is wrong. Any suggestion please. –

Add One more column in list- Previous Balance.

While you are editing the record second time, 
Set  Previous Balance= Old value of Qty, in your case 15

Then Qty= New Qty, in your case 20.

Keep in Mind- When you are adding new record-  set  Previous Balance=0 or empty.

So as per your comment
Previous Balance= 15
and then Qty= 20.

Now change your Workflow logic

The step where you are deducting the quantity

Add if condition

```
If Current Item:Previous Balance is not empty 

Set Deliver Qty to 200+Previous Balance-Qty

Else

Set Deliver Qty to 200-Qty
```

Further EDIT 2:

```
then Calculate   Variable: Balance Qty  minus Current Item:Delevery Qty (Output to vriable:calc)
```

Change this to

```
If Current Item:Previous Balance is not empty 

Calculate Variable: Balance Qty plus Current Item:Previous Balance (Output to Variable: calc )

Calculate Variable: calc minus Current Item:Delevery Qty (Output to Variable: calc )

Else

Calculate Variable: Balance Qty minus Current Item:Delevery Qty (Output to Variable: calc )
```

Comment: Yes Devang, I'm using "then update item in current list"

Comment: Are you saying that, you have selected "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed".
this means, you have all 3 checkboxes selected, in the image I have provided.

Comment: I'm using "then update item in current list" but  "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" I've not selected because if i select than my workflow will not update the first item.

Comment: Please specify why( I've not selected because if i select than my workflow will not update the first item)

Comment: I've given the workflow print screen. I'll just change the start option to check the result and update you.

Comment: Your going to have to set the "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" to true. or run the workflow manually every time you update the item.

Comment: I selected the third option "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" but edit is not working. Uploaded new print screen here for reference first I enter Qty 15 in row second its got updated but in second screen if I edit the second row from Qty 15 to 20 its not updating in first row. My workflow is working fine everything is showing correctly only I'm facing issue when I want to edit the item.

Comment: I have edited my answer to address your concerns.Please take a look

Comment: I have edited my answer further, I cant comment on Vince's post as I am lacking numbers.

Comment: Devang - I change the workflow, PFA print screen, In starting only the result is coming incorrect. Its showing result something different.

Comment: your steps dont matches with mine. can you help me understand about those changes

Comment: I have 2 Calculate Action in If block and 1 in Else block.
You have 1 in each block. So logic differs.

Comment: Devang - Sorry I missed that but PFA print after changes still result is showing incorrect only in second row new entry without edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18763/discussion-between-devang-and-user3760253).

Comment: Change your workflow as per below instruction. (calc2 to calc)

from
Calculate Variable: Balance Qty minus Current Item:Delevery Qty (Output to Variable: calc2 )

to
Calculate Variable: Balance Qty minus Current Item:Delevery Qty (Output to Variable: calc ) 

And it should resolve, if not Add log, particularly variable:calc, and post them.

Comment: I've don the changes but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what Devang said to start the workflow when the item is updated/changed.

If the workflow just needs to calculate a total value for a column why don't you rather create a view and set the Total value to calculate the sum for that column?

[image]

Are you using the correct variables when doing your calculation?
You are deducting from the Balance and not from the Total when editing the item.

Comment: Vince - Through workflow almost I've done not sure how to archive this through view which you are saying. what I'm doing is whenever user will enter the Delivery Qty, Delivery Date workflow will check the Purchase No and Part No (some time one purchase no there will be more than one part no) and update the item. I've activated the version so user can check the history using version history. Now here only concern is for every entry workflow is working fine but only if I'm going to edit the item my workflow is not updating the Delivery Qty, Delivery Date & Balance Qty.

Comment: Devang / Vince - Yes after select "then update item in current list" but "Start workflow automatically when an item is changed" now its updating. But its treating as a new value. For example (First Deliver Qty 200-10=190 then 190-15=175) so here if I'm editing the Qty from 15 to 20 so it will show the result (190-20=170) but result which I'm getting is (175-20=155) which is wrong. Any suggestion please.

Comment: This has to do with your use of variables or column your using to calculate the values. You could be using the balance column value and deducting from that. Either you need to calculate the total all over again or you'll need to add another variable and use that to get the old and new value.

Comment: Devang, Sorry I'm not much clear on your posted answer. 1) For "Previous Balance" what will be the column type. 2) In workflow the condition you have give so (Please find my above attached workflow print screen) I'm already using if else condition where I've to add this condition.I'm little confuse, If you provide some example or print screen it will be helpful.Thanks

Comment: If you want the Balance Qty to be 180 when changing the Delivery Qty from 20 to 15 you need to calculate on the Pu.Oder Qty minus Delivery Qty? (200-20=180) See above image of your workflow variables are different. You are deducting from the Balance Qty.

Comment: Devan - I think you are saying to create column "Previous Balance" Type "Text". Now when I'm going to enter the data in list for "New Record / Item" in "Previous Balance" column Qty will "0". AND for Editing the record second time in "Previous Balance" column Qty will be old Qty. Let me know if this is correct.....Now about workflow I understand but where to add not sure as already IF ELSE condition is there. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the confusion.. Let me provide the full print screen about my workflow which I'm using.

Comment: In the if statement part of your workflow change the "Variable: Balance Qty" to the "Current Item:PU" and then run the workflow and post your results?

Comment: Sure Vince..I just uploaded the workflow which I'm using. Please have a look if I'm missing something also I'm will try to "Current Item:PU" and updateyou

Comment: Vince - I checked and this is correct only. Here we have to deduct the Qty in two way.1) (Pu. Order Qty-Delivery Qty = Balance Qty) which is in else statement) Balance Qty(OLD) - Deliver Qty = Balance Qty(NEW). If I'm doing changes as per your above comment it's always deducting from Pu.OrderQty.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Devang for your help. Here I'm just posting the final solution provided by Devang.
1) Below workflow need to create.
2) This important while doing entry in Previous Balance Column - When you are adding new record- set Previous Balance=0 or empty.
- While you are editing the record second time, Set Previous Balance= Old value of Qty.

Also I got one simple workaround - Instead of Edit if you want you can use the workflow which I've attached in Question section. just enter one more entry and the quantity which you want to deduct enter with minus sign Example :- You received Qty 10 and you have enter 20 so here add one more item for the particular Order No & Part No and Order Qty enter -10 and you will get the result as per expectation. Note :- Here you have to use workflow which I've attached in my question section. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate then you column type as calculated column and write formula of deducting column which you from 100.

For eg: Column a is 40 and you column b as 60(100-40) then u can create column b as calculated column and write formula as : =100-[a]

Comment: Kaush - that I was already try but the problem was when Qty was deducting in multiple lot in different date the I was confuse to update the list. FYI please fine above list.